# Jquery ajax not calling server side function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have solution structure as:

[image]

I want to call recommendationProcess function from CTL_RateRecommendationDetails.ascx.cs from

CTL_RateRecommendationDetails.ascx

So i written code as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UserControls/CTL_RateRecommendationDetails.ascx/recommendationProcess",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(value) {
        alert(value.d);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Ajax Error" + JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

But every time it comes in error block.

I have tried with :

```
url: "/CTL_RateRecommendationDetails.ascx/recommendationProcess",
```

And

```
url: "CTL_RateRecommendationDetails.ascx/recommendationProcess",
```

But its not calling function.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void recommendationProcess()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Any Error in `console`?

Comment: When you say it's not calling the function, what error do you get?

Comment: No error in console but function does not gets called

Comment: If there is no error and the function isn't called then your event that makes the AJAX request isn't bound properly. If the request works but doesn't find the endpoint then you'd see a 404 in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call code behinds of user controls from JQuery Ajax

Ref : http://forums.asp.net/t/1423555.aspx

[Using jQuery AJAX to call ASP.NET function in control code-behind instead of page code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392345/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-asp-net-function-in-control-code-behind-instead-of-pag)

[how-to-access-server-side-method-in-ascx-control-using-jquery-ajax-method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e287f7bf-d24a-47f3-8af1-d513c48867df/how-to-access-server-side-method-in-ascx-control-using-jquery-ajax-method?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)