# I have issue regarding ascx user control method calling by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ascx

I have user control which is included in most of my aspx page. This user control shows huge data from database. Now I have decided to fetch that by jquery. I am very much familiar with jquery and how to call server side method by jquery. My problem is that I can not specify ascx file in jquery ajax post method. Like

```
function loadMore() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Left.ascx/LoadData",
        data: "{PageIndex:1}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I can not call ascx code behind method by jquery because ASCX is not directly served via URL.
I cannot write even C# code for loading & populating ascx from aspx server side method dynamically because it has been used in many aspx. So now I am in problem. No easy & good idea is coming to my mind...so I am stuck. Please show me the way to achieve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the ascx method directly.  What you have to do is call an aspx page method and from that call the user control method.  This sounded familiar so I checked.  I have an answer to a similar question here:

[Jquery .ajax async postback on C# UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539620/jquery-ajax-async-postback-on-c-sharp-usercontrol/2539913#2539913)

which shows the way this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to get HTML back from your response?  Possibly so you can just set the contents of a div instead of having to build the html on the client.  If that is the case, then make a new aspx page that contains your ascx and have the ascx databind in the page load of the aspx.